# Is there a URI schema for addressing individual email messages?

Tags: email, uri

When someone loses track of an email that has been sent to them, and brings that to the sender's attention, it is common practice for the sender to simply forward or re-send the original email. I want to know if there is any [semi-]standard way to reference a specific email, such that a mail client could open that email if it has a copy of it. This might be in the form of a URI, or possibly some other form. Such a URI might reference the sender, recipient, date, time, or other headers that [should] remain intact between sender and recipient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Message-ID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID) is a globally unique identifier for messages.

Note that the `Message-ID` header is [optional, but recommended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4):

> Though listed as optional in the table in section 3.6, every message SHOULD have a "Message-ID:" field.

[RFC 2392](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392) specifies the URI scheme `mid` (which was already reserved in [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-4)):

> The "mid" scheme uses (a part of) the message-id of an email message to refer to a specific message.

An [example](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392#section-2) from RFC 2392:

```
<A HREF="mid:960830.1639@XIson.com/partA.960830.1639@XIson.com">previous message</A>, shows how the approach you propose can be used to accomplish ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I doubt any client supports it, but it's a start!

Comment: @Sparr: I don’t know of any client support (might be a good question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)). Mailing lists often show the message-ID and allow linking/searching it, but they map it to HTTP URLs of course, e.g., [at the W3C](http://www.w3.org/Mail/#searching): appending the message-id at `http://www.w3.org/mid/` redirects to a link to this particular message.

Comment: Sparr’s question for client support on Super User: [What email clients support cid: and mid: URIs?](http://superuser.com/q/681421/151741)